# Why is Quartz.net ignoring the misfire threshold?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jobs, quartz.net, threshold

I want to ignore the execution of a job if it has expired. By expiration I mean 60 seconds after `next_fire_time`.

I pause the job, wait 5 minutes, resume it and job executes, even though I've set `["org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000"` in Scheduler properties. Why is this happening? I want to procceed a job execution only if **60 seconds have not passed after** `next_fire_time`. In other way I want the job execution to be ignored.

Doesn't the threshold mean how long the job can still be executed after the `next_fire_time`?
It seems like setting misfireThreshold doesn't make any difference.

Comment: `misfireThreshold` defines how late the trigger should be to be considered misfired.If delayed execution time is greater than or equal to misfireThreshold,it is misfired.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

1. It's `["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000"`, not `["org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000"`
2. I needed `WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing` and I've used `WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed`, which doesn't care about threshold.